# Angular 6 - Show dynamic div when selected a name

Tags: angular

I've an Array and the Array content is displaying as checkbox list of employee names. I want, when I select a checkbox (selecting employee name), it'll show a DIV which contains the selected employee name and a textarea (for comments) for the relevant employee. That DIV would be dynamically show for every selected name from the list.
Please guide me in this how can I achieve the required result.

Comment: You need to send an `ajax` call when someone selects a user name and fetch data with respect to that `user` and show on `div` element.

Comment: Please take a look at one of the angular training, your question is covered in there

Comment: `this.filteredArray = this.yourEmployeeArray.filter(item => item.selected == true)` whenever a checkbox state has changed. Bind your `div` via `ngFor`to the `filteredArray`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that like this:

In your component.ts:

```ts
selectedEmployees: string[];

toggleEmployee(empl: string): void {
    const index = this.selectedEmployees.indexOf(empl)
    if(index > -1) {
        this.selectedEmployees.push(empl);
    } else {
        this.selectedEmployees.splice(index, 1);
    }       
}
```

in your html:

```html
<input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleEmployees('James')" value="James">
<input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleEmployees('Charles')" value="Charles">

<div *ngIf="let empl of selectedEmployees">
   {{ empl }}
<div>
```

I hope this answers your question